# Google Cloud Platform firewall

Tags: google-cloud-platform, fivem

I am running google cloud instance to host an fivem game server, the fivem game runs an web server on port 40120 for the server owner to open up in an web browser and setup the server through an GUI web interface, I am trying to access the web page but my web browser http://ip:40120 took to long to respond. I have opened up port 40120 on tcp and udp on the linux machine and through the GCP firewall on the dashboard and performed an server restart and still not letting me access the page.

I have ran the IP through an port checker and it states that the specified port (40120) is closed.

[image]

Comment: Does your FTP run on the Compute Engine? What are your GCP firewall rule configuration?

Comment: I am attempting to run an web server to setup my fivem game server. The port in question is 40120 and in the GCP firewall I have port 40120 enabled pointing to 0.0.0.0/0.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/dMhLgfy here is an screenshot of the firewall configuration for the port 40120

Answer (score 0):

When i was created these firewall rules I was setting the tags to be fivem-server and not adding the tag to the instance that I was trying to apply to rules to that instance being instance-2 after doing that and performing and system reboot I can now connect to the web server.